# How can SE sites use personal information, like e-mail addresses?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, spam, email, privacy

I submitted a question to `startups.com` in February 2010. In the last month, I've received two unsolicited emails from them. It seems they are abandoning the Q&A aspect of their site and they are trying to advertise their new service.

I'm not going to complain too much about two e-mails, but it did make me wonder if all these newfangled Stack Exchange sites I'm registering for are going to start spamming me. Does Stack Exchange, Inc. place any restrictions on the way its participating sites can use personal information (like e-mail addresses)?

EDIT: I'm referring to http://answers.startups.com/, not http://answers.onstartups.com/.

<s>@reemrevnivek claims that http://answers.startups.com/ is an old SE 1.0 site.</s> @mmyers says it is. In my mind, that doesn't change my question or concern. My expectation as a user is that since Stack Overflow doesn't spam me with e-mails that don't pertain to my own activity on the site, other sites that use SE technology (or partnership or however that relationship is defined) won't do it either.

Comment: [OnStartups](http://onstartups.com) is not a Stack Exchange site, but [Answers.OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/) is. I would have expected them to have separate logins.

Comment: @ChrisF - **On** Startups *is* a Stack Exchange site.  It's http://answers.startups.com/ that looks like an SE site but is actually an old SE 1.0 site now maintained by http://www.killerstartups.com/.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, that does not appear to be the case. http://answers.startups.com has links back to the rest of the SE network in the footer, which indicates that it is part of the network.

Comment: @mmyers - There are no links to the rest of the network in the footer.  Posting an answer with screenshots for clarification.

Comment: Okay, wait, this is weird. [The A51 page for the current answers.onstartups.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6243/startup-business) states "This site was seeded with content from answers.onstartups.com, a Stack Exchange 1.0 site." However, [answers.startups.com](http://answers.startups.com/) (without the on) doesn't have the standard SE footer and has the SE 1.0 tag `<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">` in its source. Was there a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The site you are referring to, answers.startups.com, was part of the SE 1.0 network.  It is not in any way related to the actual Stack Exchange site answers.onstartups.com that Stack Exchange, Inc. administers.

Under the 1.0 model, that we've since abandoned, we were only providing the software to 3rd parties (in this case, the company your question should be directed to is [startups.com](http://startups.com/)).  Think phpBB.  That company's [contact form is here](http://startups.com/contacts/add).

Unfortunately, we don't have any input into their actions concerning the info you've given them (such as your email address) and this is one of the reasons why we abandoned that model.

Although this doesn't address your issue, our plan is to eventually migrate those old SE 1.0 sites that do not want to be part of the 2.0 network off of our infrastructure and we've been doing that progressively.

Answer (score 10):

To clarify which site we're talking about, here are a few screenshots:

## http://answers.startups.com/

Note the lack of an "On" in the URL.   This site is not on the new Stack Exchange platform, and is run by startups.com.

Header:

[image: header]

Excerpt from privacy policy (http://askme.startups.com/privacy/):

[image: privacy policy]

Footer (note absence of Stack Exchange network sites):

[image: footer]

---

## http://answers.onstartups.com/

Note the presence of "On" in the URL.  This site is part of the new Stack Exchange network, and is run by Stack Exchange Inc.

Header:

[image: header]

Excerpt from privacy policy (https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy):

[image: privacy policy]

Footer (note presence of Stack Exchange network sites):

[image: footer]

---

If you're receiving lots of unsolicited emails from the latter, that's cause for concern and can be discussed here.  If you're receiving mail from the former, you'll have to take it up with them.

Comment: Wow. Next time I will copy-and-paste the URL instead of typing it out. I thought I was on answers.startups.com all the time.